# How Can I unzip and copy specific file using Ant

Tags: ant, unzip

I have zip file "A.zip".It contains a folder "B".Inside this folder I have simple "a.sql" file.which I need to copy to destination folder "Test".I have used below code but still it is not working.Please let me know how can I do it.

```
<target name="unzip.ubview" description="Unzips the zipped dump file from latest build">
<echo message="Extracting zip file" />
<unzip src="${IMP_LOC}/A.zip" dest="E:/Test" overwrite="true">
    <patternset>
        <include name="a*.sql"/>
    </patternset>
    <mapper>
        <globmapper from="B/*" to="*"/>
    </mapper>
    </unzip>
</target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
<target name="unzip.ubview" description="Unzips the zipped dump file from latest build">
<echo message="Extracting zip file" />
<unzip src="${IMP_LOC}/A.zip" dest="E:/Test" overwrite="true">
    <patternset>
        <include name="B/a*.sql"/>
    </patternset>
    <mapper>
        <globmapper from="B/*" to="*"/>
    </mapper>
    </unzip>
</target>
```